# The smooth Nullstellensatz

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $n$ be a positive integer, let $f_1, \ldots, f_r : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth functions, let $Z_i = f_i^{-1} \{ 0 \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and suppose $Z_1 \cap \cdots \cap Z_r = \emptyset$.

**Question.** Must there exist smooth functions $g_1, \ldots, g_r : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_1 g_1 + \cdots + f_r g_r = 1$?

I believe the answer is no in general. On the other hand:

- It suffices to show that there exist smooth functions $g_1, \ldots, g_r : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_1 g_1 + \cdots + f_r g_r$ vanishes nowhere, because we can rescale. Therefore a counterexample will have the property that, for *any* smooth functions $g_1, \ldots, g_r : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $f_1 g_1 + \cdots + f_r g_r$ vanishes *somewhere*.
- If $0$ is a regular value for each $f_i$, then the answer is yes: take a partition of unity $h_1 + \cdots + h_r = 1$ where each $h_i$ has support contained in $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus Z_i$ and then define $g_i = h_i / f_i$.
- If we replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{C}$ and "smooth" with "polynomial", then this is a special case of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

Comment: With $g_i=f_i$ you'll get a non vanishing function right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $f(x) = (f_1(x),...,f_r(x))^T$, then we see that $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$.

Let $g(x) = {1 \over \|f(x)\|^2} f(x)$, then we see that $\langle g(x), f(x) \rangle = 1$ for all $x$.

(And $g(x) = (g_1(x),...,g_r(x))^T$.)

Comment: Ah, how did I forget the old trick of summing the squares...

Comment: My arrival at a solution was much more convoluted that the above might suggest :-).

Comment: Very nice and elementary: +1